# config.ru get URL parameter

Tags: ruby, passenger

I have a ruby cartridge installed on my app on openshift and now I have a problem. I need to edit `config.ru` file and get the parameter from the url.

I tried to write something like this in config.ru:

```
map '/verif/:txt' do
  do_job = proc do |env|
    [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, [:txt]]
  end
  run do_job

end
```

I need a way to get that parameter from the URL, so, if I go in browser and type http://url_to_the_app/verif/thisIsAtest => the result shoud be thisIsAtest.

Comment: You will find the path in `env[PATH_INFO]`

Comment: maybe use a middleware? if you are using rails, you can use a proc in the production.rb file that will be called in every request.